# How to connect my Docker application to a remote database?

Tags: java, spring, database, spring-boot, docker

I have 2 Spring boot application running in docker. 
The both application connects to a Postgres database running in another machine. 
Before I put the application in a container, I used to make a ssh tunnel from localhost to connect the another machine that contains the database running this command:

```
> ssh -vnN *user*@*host* -p *port* -L 5433:user-host.local:5432
```

In this way, I can set *localhost:5433* in my **application.properties** file to connect the remote database, that is running in port 5432. 
This is **application.properties** file from SpringBoot application:

```
>spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5433/*database*...\
>spring.datasource.username = *user*\
>spring.datasource.password = *password*
```

But now, running this same application in a container, I know that *localhost* refers to container ip. And I can't connect to the remote database. 
I dont know how can I access the same remote database using a SSH tunnel.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solved!** 
In the case for the others who had the same problem:

In the file **aplication.properties** of my application, I needed to change the *spring.datasource.url* to point to host's ip

new **application.properties**

> spring.datasource.url =
> jdbc:postgresql://***host_ip_here***:5433/database... 
> spring.datasource.username = user 
> spring.datasource.password = password

and then, in the host machine I can execute the ssh command to link to the remote database, but now, adding the host's ip before the mapping port.
In this way, I'm telling to docker that every request done that acess the host'ip in the port 5433, will be forward to database-machine-host, in port 5432 (default postgres port)

> ssh -vnN *user*@*host* -p *port* -L ***host_ip_here***:5433:user-host.local:5432

I know there is others solutions to this problem, so if you have a better one, please text here!